# Cookies in angular / php?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am working on a simple voting app with one questions. I would like the users to be directed to the results page if they had already voted through a cookie.

Is it better to manipulate the cookies through PHP or through AngularJS ngcookies API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **localStorage** (or called Supercookies) of the system

You can store data via JavaScript, of course, no AngularJS is required here:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

You get it later via

```
var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

you get `undefined` when the key does not exist, so just check

```
var value = localStorage(key);
if (value == 'undefined') { ... }
```

Of course there is way to set a cookie with PHP:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
```

Access and check with:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) { ... }
```

Comment: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage - There's a good module for it. It has built in cookie fallback.